# Is Auto Reorder available in nopcommerce from customer front side?

Tags: nopcommerce

We are customizing the nopCommerce for one of our client.

They need the functionality to auto reorder from customer front where customer select the cycle period and cycle times, they don't need Recurring product where admin set the cycle period and cycle times.

Comment: Something like a subscription? If you can't find it, searching for "subscription" plugins might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of now, NopCommerce dont have such feature out of the box, so what you will have to do is create a plugin for it.

here is what you might look at.

1) create a table with customer id, product id, starting date, ending date, interval.

2) customer frontend view make design should support subscribing to a product, and post data to your plugin, and insert record in the new table for each product.

3) have a schedule task run daily against that table for orders that are due.